# Smooth Div Scroll - Start scrolling after delay

Tags: jquery, delay, smooth-scrolling

I am using the jQuery Plugin Smooth Div Scroll, it works perfectly fine but i would like the scrolling to start not immediately but after a delay of two seconds.

Here is how it looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
        mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
        manualContinuousScrolling: true,
        autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
    });
});
</script>
```

Here are all the options explained: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/options.html

Could someone maybe take a quick look? I'm stuck unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

There's a public method `startAutoScrolling`, combine that with `setTimeout`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
        mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
        manualContinuousScrolling: true
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("startAutoScrolling");
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Worked very well! Thanks, @Mati.